# Unity3D - Detect a vertex on planet mesh without cubes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, vertex

I have a planet mesh that I am generating procedurally (based on a random seed).  The generator creates tectonic plates and moves them creating the land masses, mountains and water depressions you see below; ~2500 points in a planet.  The textured surface is just a shader.

[image]

Each vertex will have information associated with it, and I need to know which vertex they are pointing at to relay this information.

I am looking for a way identify which vertex they are pointing at.  The current solution is to generate a cube at each vertex, then use a collider/Ray to identify it.  The two white cubes in the picture above are for testing.

What I want to know is if there is a better way to identify the vertex without generating cubes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. if you're doing such awesome and advanced work, surely you know about this

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-triangleIndex.html

2. when working with mesh, it's totally commonplace to need the nearest vertex.

note that very simply, you just **find the nearest one**, ie look over them all for the nearest.

(it's incredibly fast to do this, you only have a tiny number of verts so there's no way performance will even be measurable.)

{Consider that, of course, you could break the object in to say 8 pieces - but that's just something you have to do anyway in many cases, for example a race track, so it can occlude properly.}